# memcached php sessions on heroku

Tags: php, session, heroku

I had noticed that an application I have setup on heroku only shows sessions variables on random requests when I refresh the browser. I put this down to the fact the application is running on 5 dynos.

I followed the following tutorial to solve this with memcached using memcachedcloud.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-sessions#storing-sessions-in-memcached

The issue still remains though. I am using the PHP slim framework, is there any further config I need for this? I cant seem to find anything in the slim docs.

EDIT:

I can not produce the required composer.lock file because when running.

```
composer update
```

I get the error

```
The requested PHP extension ext-memcached * is missing from your system.
```

But it is in fact installed. I can see the version from typing.

```
memcached -h
```

But it is not present when typing

```
composer show --platform
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what platform you're running, you have to make sure you that composer updates. Even if you have memcached installed, it has to match your PHP version. Then, once installed, run `composer update`

For example:

If you have PHP5.6.15, get memcached with, either, `brew install php56/memcached` or `sudo apt-get install php56/memcached`.

Then run `composer update`.

If you have an issue installing composer on Mac, you have to enable `rootless` install. More info can be found here:

https://donatstudios.com/OS-X-Mavericks-Memcached-PHP-Extension-Installation

The gist of the steps to take are:

- Restart computer and hold Command + R to get into recover mode
- Get into the terminal from Utilities
- Run `csrutil disable` and restart

This should be done prior to installing `memcached` from Homebrew.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I was getting the same "ext-memcached * is missing" error and could not see `ext-memcached` when running `composer show --platform`.

I noticed that when I originally installed memcached, homebrew showed me various alternatives. So on Mac OSX El Capitan, I ended up installing the one that matched my PHP version:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php55-memcached
```

And then I had to add it to php.ini:

```
extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php55-memcached/2.2.0/memcached.so
```

You can get the correct version path with:

```
brew info php55-memcached
```

And then I restarted Apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

It finally showed up in the composer list and I was able to update composer without error.